# How do I use ng-options with an object data source index by integers?

Tags: angularjs

I have a `<select>` element with its `ng-options` attribute set to an object data source:

```
<select id="mySelect3"
        name="mySelect3"
        ng-model="mySelect3"
        ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in objectDataSourceInts"></select>
```

The object data source is indexed with integers instead of strings:

```
$scope.objectDataSourceInts = {
    1: 'one'
  , 2: 'two'
  , 4: 'four'
  , 6: 'six'
};
```

I’m trying to set the value of this element in my controller on page load:

```
$scope.mySelect3 = 6;
```

I’d expect the matching value ('six') to be the selected option in the `<select>` on page load, but it’s not. An empty option is selected instead.

Full Plunk example: http://plnkr.co/edit/OWePopAWAIy9qcgNgQE6?p=preview

How can I set this value on page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha — it looks like I need to specify the key as a string, not its original integer form, when setting the value for this field. So, instead of:

```
$scope.mySelect3 = 6;
```

I do this:

```
$scope.mySelect3 = "6";
```

And it works as expected.

http://plnkr.co/edit/OWePopAWAIy9qcgNgQE6?p=preview